# Does a keyboard short cut exist in Visual Studio 2010 to debug the current project?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a solution with 36 projects.
When I'm working on one of the projects I'd like to be able to debug it without having to right click the project then select 'debug' then select 'start new instance'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could add in the Options dialog under Environment->Keyboard `"ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance"` as a shortcut. 
This starts debugging on the current project.

(maybe this changed a bit for 2010)

source: http://www.sharpdevel.com/2009/09/visual-studio-debug-start-new-instance.html

Comment: Works great with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: When I added "ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.Startnewinstance", Ctrl+V (Paste) option got dis baled, I removed that and now able to use the Ctrl+V options again... any other alternative to have the keyboard short cut to debug the current project ?

Comment: Is there a way to start new instance of current project, but without debugger attached?

Comment: and for Visual Studio 2017 :)

Comment: I assigned it to alt+shift+F5, wasn't taken, works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One thing that you could do is to right click your Solution, go to Properties. Select 'Startup Project' and choose 'Current selection'. After this, the project that you click will be set as startup project. You can debug the project that you want by clicking it and pressing F5 (or whatever key you have for start debugging).

Comment: Wow, where has this been for the last 20 years!  Thanks!  Works with VS 2013.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to add keyboard shortcut to debug the present project instead of the solution:

1. Open VisualStudio2010 > Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard
2. Show commands containing "StartNewInstance" 
   and you will see:  "ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Debug.StartNewInstance"
3. Enter your choice into "Press shortcut keys"  (for example Alt-F5)
4. Click the Assign button
5. OK

Away you go.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, the keyboard shortcut to start debugging is:

<kbd>F5</kbd>